# Why does not sequence work with List of Validations

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative, traversable

I think I understand what [sequence](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.syntax.TraverseOps) is. I am wondering why it does not work with `List[ValidationNel]`. For instance:

The `sequence` works fine with `List[Option]]`

```
scala> val os = List(1.some, 2.some)
os: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2))

scala> os.sequence
res10: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))
```

... but does not work with `List[ValidationNel]`

```
scala> val vs: List[ValidationNel[String, Int]] = List(Success(1), Success(2))
vs: List[scalaz.ValidationNel[String,Int]] = List(Success(1), Success(2))

scala> vs.sequence
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev:scalaz.Leibniz.===[scalaz.ValidationNel[String,Int],G[B]]
```

... however `sequenceU` *does* work with `List[ValidationNel]`

```
scala> vs.sequenceU
res14: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],List[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2))
```

My questions are: Why does not `sequence` work with `List[ValidationNel]` ? Why does `sequenceU` work with it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.sequenceU uses the Unapply technique to derive the correct types, where as for .sequence you need to manually provide the types for it.

To make things a bit more annoying, the first type argument of sequence needs a type parameter that takes one type parameter not two like ValidationNel. So you either type lambda it, or do a local type definition.

Try

```
type X = ValidationNel[String,X]

vs.sequence[X, Int]
```

or

```
vs.sequence[({type l[A]=ValidationNel[String,A]})#l,Int]
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you for the explanation. One more question: why does `sequence` work with `List[Option]` w/o any type parameter ?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I guess List[Option] can be easily destructured into the correct type shapes (i.e. without the need for type lambdas) so the type system can figure out what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I find that more often than not, .sequence needs type parameters to work.

Comment: `Option` is a 1-parameter type. The compiler knows that `sequence` requires a type parameter `G[_]`. It can infer that for `Option[String]` `G` is `Option`, but for `ValidationNel[String, Int]` it doesn't know what `G` is.

Comment: @lmm Thanks. So the problem is the number of type parameters. I see it now.

Comment: is it valid to use `X` in such a circular way ? ```type X = ValidationNel[String,X]```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on Scalaz.

To be short, because ValidationNel is not monad, so this conversion is **not** valid:

> List[ValidationNel[SomeType]] => ValidationNel[List[SomeType]]

as the error message shows: `implicit value not found`, which indicates no such conversion.

Comment: I am afraid it is not true. Monads are _not_ commutative. Applicatives (those that aren't monads) -- are.